# Moving a webapps location from Tomcat 9 installation directory to another path

Tags: tomcat

I installed tomcat 9 following a tutorial of https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-9-on-debian-10
so an installtion path got `/opt/tomcat`

Then I decided to move the `webapps` folder to another path on a file system. My try was to associate the path to a `appBase` variable in a host configuration in a `conf/server.xml` file in this way:

```
  <Host name="localhost"
    <!-- appBase="webapps" -->
        appBase="/opt/tomcat/webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

    <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
    -->

    <!-- Access log processes all example.
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
         Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

  </Host>
```

This did not work so the `appBase` variable could not get a value of an absolute path. How to move the `webapps` folder to another location, for example to a user directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the below tag in server.xml file.

```
<Host name="localhost" appBase="/opt/tomcat/webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```